# how to fire two oracle insert statement together?Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle11g

I am trying to fire two insert statements at a time. Actually i have tried with below query but its inserting in only one table.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from abc.test where test_NAME = ''aaa''' BULK COLLECT INTO T_SC;
IF T_SC.count = 0 THEN
    Insert into abc.test (test_ID,test_NAME,status) 
    VALUES(1,'aaa','a') BULK COLLECT INTO insert_cnt;
    IF insert_cnt.count = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO abc.test1(test1_id,test1_NAME,test1_ALIAS,test_ID)
    VALUES(1,'bbb','b',1);
    COMMIT;
END IF;
```

it is only inserting in abc.test1 table..What i am going to missing. If anyone knows than plz help me in this.

Comment: Trigger  can be useful in such case. Look into that.

Comment: @vjshah: I dont want to use trigger because I am just writing script. thats why.

Comment: You can go for stored procedures where you can easily use two insert statement together and also trigger operations. Btw,in your code,you got two if's but single end if..Look into that.

Comment: This is no way needs/warrants triggers.

Answer (score 0):

This whole code of yours doesn't seem right:

1. why the dynamic sql ?
2. there are lots of syntax errors

   - unclosed "if" (as vj shah commented)
   - missing `returning` keyword
3. why do you need the `bulk collect` if your returning from the insert only one row ?
4. what is the second "if" for ?

and so on...

Anyway, this code works:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from abc.test where test_NAME = ''aaa''' BULK COLLECT INTO T_SC;

/* BTW, why not 
select * bulk collect into T_SC from abc.test where test_NAME = 'aaa';
*/

IF T_SC.count = 0 THEN
    Insert into abc.test (test_ID, test_NAME, status) 
    VALUES(1,'aaa','a') returning test_ID, test_NAME, status BULK COLLECT INTO insert_cnt;
    IF insert_cnt.count = 1 THEN
       INSERT INTO abc.test1(test1_id,test1_NAME,test1_ALIAS,test_ID)
       VALUES(1,'bbb','b',1);
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END IF;
```

Comment: Giving me this error while using your code. `Error at Command Line:1 Column:9
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.
`

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your problem a little better. Neither your logic nor the data that you show gives any idea of what you are trying to accomplish. (the logic behind the if).

This is also not functional code (too many syntax errors), can you update with the real code you are firing? May be just change the table names?

If you want to make sure both the statements either complete successfully or both of them are rolled back, your approach of including them in a block is correct.

```
SQL> create table test_rc_2(
  2    id number
  3  );

Table created.
```

--Sample 1 : Submitting inserts seperately (only the latest statement is rolled

```
SQL> insert into test_rc_2 values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_rc_2 values ('hello');
insert into test_rc_2 values ('hello')
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test_rc_2;

        ID
----------
       100
```

--case 2 : submittig them in a block.

```
    SQL> truncate table test_rc_2
      2  ;

    Table truncated.

    SQL> begin
      2    insert into test_rc_2 values(100);
      3    insert into test_rc_2 values('hello..');
      4  end;
      5  /
    begin
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01722: invalid number
    ORA-06512: at line 3

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test_rc_2;

no rows selected
```